# How to print a curly bracket in a VSCode snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm writing a snippet for VSCode. I mean to write a line with three fields:

```
name {nickName} jobTitle
```

The second field "nickName" may or may not exist: if it exists it has curly brackets, if it does not exist there are not even curly brackets.

I'm trying the following snippet:

```json
"New Item": {
    "scope": "markdown",
    "prefix": "new-item",
    "body": "${1:name} ${2:{${3:nickname}}} ${4:job title}",
    "description": "Insert a new item"
  }
```

The first brace is managed correctly: if I keep it I can modify the "nickName" field, but if I remove it the "nickName" field also disappears. The problem is that the second bracket, however, always remains outside the management of the snippet and must, if necessary, be deleted by hand.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer. It's perfectly OK if you answer your own question.

Comment: @PeterMacej Yes, I think so too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The solution is

```json
"New Item": {
  "scope": "markdown",
  "prefix": "new-item",
  "body": "${1:name} ${2:{${3:nickname}\\}} ${4:job title}",
  "description": "Insert a new item"
}
```

(note the double backslash).